# How to get details of an appointment as string in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone, appointment

I'm using this code to get appointments in windows phone 8

```
private void SearchAppointments_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Appointments appts = new Appointments();
    appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Appointments_SearchCompleted);
    appts.SearchAsync(DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),20);
}
```

now I need to get subject (or location & etc.) of appointments as string
Can anybody help me please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.userdata.appointments.searchcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you can get search appointment result from `e.Results` in the `SearchCompleted` event handler :

```
private void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var appointment in e.Results)
    {
        //here you can get each Appointment detail
        String location = appointment.Location;
        String subject = appointment.Subject;
        ......
    }
}
```